# How to write a method to take arbitrary classes in Scala

Tags: scala, structural-typing

What would be the correct way to write a method that operates on any class
that has an addition operation defined?

I imagined it was something like

```
def trajectory[A <: {def +(a:A):A}](a:A): A = {
    a + a
}
```

but it is not working.

Answer (score 3):

I would go with a [type class](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Type_class):

```
trait Semigroup[A] {
  def mappend(a0: A, a: A): A
}

object Semigroup {
  implicit val intAdditionSemigroup: Semigroup[Int] = new Semigroup[Int] {
    override def mappend(a0: Int, a: Int): Int = a0 + a
  }
}
```

When you want to utilize it, you add it as an implicit constraint on the type parameter:

```
def foo[A](a0: A, a: A)(implicit semigroup: Semigroup[A]): A = {
  semigroup.mappend(a0, a)
}
```